# Performance engineering: Inconsistent results in measuring turnaround time

Tags: java, performance

I am having difficulty wording this problem since this is my first assignment for measuring throughput of a feature.

The problem is when I run a set of tests against an application server, sometimes I get average of 27 seconds turnaround time for each unit of work. And after few seconds, I start getting 10 seconds turnaround time per unit work (while executing same set of tests). How can someone explain this? I am the only person using this server so I cannot blame it on any other testing.

Comment: What input sizes are you using? When testing the thoughput of an algorithm, we tend to use large input sizes to help standardize results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Answer (score 4):

Probably the JIT is kicking in after a few seconds, and compiles your code to native code so that it runs faster. There could also be a caching effect going on, where warm (CPU and disk) caches speed up the run.

To get reproducible results when doing performance measurements, it's essential to burn the task in for a while until the metrics stabilize.